# Extending Scala collections

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I would like to derive a version of a Scala built-in collection that expands on the functionality for a particular generic type e.g.,

```
import scala.collection.immutable._
class Tuple2Set[T1,T2] extends HashSet[Tuple2[T1,T2]] {
 def left = map ( _._1 )
 def right = map ( _._2 )
}
```

However when I try to use it with the following test

```
  new Tuple2Set[String,String]() + (("x","y")) left
```

I get the following compile error

```
error: value left is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.HashSet[(String, String)]
```

How can I change the class so that this works?

Comment: I am new to Scala, can anybody explain what `map( _._1 )` means hear? As I understand for example `set.map(_ + 1)` will create new set with elements incremented by one, but i cannot get what `_._1` does

Comment: @Vetal: `(_._1)` in this context is the same as `((x: Tuple[T1, T2]) => x._1)` and `_1` is field in `Tulple2` class that represents first element of the tuple.

Comment: @Easy Thanks, if I could I would accept your answer

Comment: Vetal, `_X` are methods on tuples that return the x-th component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **Kevin Wright** said, `+` operation will return back `HashSet`. Type class `CanBuildFrom` is used to build new collections during operations like `map`. So if you want `+` to return `Tuple2Set` instead of `HashSet` you should implement `CanBuildFrom` and make it implicitly available in companion object like this:

```
object Tuple2Set {
    implicit def canBuildFrom[T1, T2] = 
        new CanBuildFrom[Tuple2Set[T1, T2], (T1, T2), Tuple2Set[T1, T2]] {...}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer seems to solve the problem of how to get + to return a more specific type, but I think a solution with some kind of wrapping may be better in general. For my actual problem I want the Tuple2Set to wrap a database and then provide "optimized" implementations of find, exists etc. I think I would actually be better off just writing a new interface in the end...

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure you really need to extend Scala collection?  To make the code above work you can do this:

```
class Tuple2Set[T1,T2](set: Set[(T1, T2)]) {
  def left = set map ( _._1 )
  def right = set map ( _._2 )
}

implicit def toTuple2Set[T1, T2](set: Set[(T1, T2)]) = new Tuple2Set(set)

Set[(String, String)]() + (("x","y")) left
```

In this case `Tuple2Set` is just the wrapper for any other `Set` implementations. This means you are not limited to `HashSet` anymore and your methods `left` and `right` will be available on any other implementations as well (like TreeSet).

I think in most cases wrapping or composition+delegation works much better than inheritance (and causes  less problems).

Comment: Could you make these two separate answers so they can be voted on separately? See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice for the offical ettiquite on this. (And yes, your explanation of `CanBuildFrom` is worth a separate answer form Kevin Wright's answer.)

Answer (score 4):

The general answer to your question is a bit too involved for a response here. But it has been written up in some [web pages](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections-impl.html).

The same material with more context is also in the 2nd edition of our book, Programming in Scala, Artima Press.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your example doesn't work is that the return type of the `+` operation is a `HashSet` and not a `Tuple2Set`.

You'll have much more luck using the "pimp my library" pattern instead of inheritance.